# Trying to simulate a BCD adder: unexpected IDENTIFIER error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, test-bench

I'm trying to simulate a BCD adder by instantiating full adder modules. Compiling the code without the test module ran fine. However, I'm currently having issues with my testbench. It's showing an error:

> near "tb_C": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting .* or '.'.

I'm currently trying to learn the top-down approach of HDL.

```
//Half Adder (HA) module
module half_adder(output S, Co, input a, b);

    xor U1(S, a, b); 
    and U2(Co, a, b);
    
endmodule

//Full Adder (FA) module
module full_adder(output S, Co, input a, b, cin); 

    wire ha_S0, ha_Co0, ha_Co1; 

    half_adder HA1(ha_S0, ha_Co0, a, b);   //instance 1 of HA
    half_adder HA2(S, ha_Co1, ha_S0, cin); //instance 2 of HA

    or U3(Co, ha_Co0, ha_Co1); 
    
endmodule

//4-bit Full Parallel Adder
module yonbit_pa(input [3:0]a, [3:0]b, cin, output [3:0]S, Cout);

    wire [2:0]Co;

    full_adder FA1(S[0], Co[0], a[0], b[0], cin);
    full_adder FA2(S[1], Co[1], a[1], b[1], Co[0]);
    full_adder FA3(S[2], Co[2], a[2], b[2], Co[1]);
    full_adder FA4(S[3], Cout,  a[3], b[3], Co[2]);

endmodule

//Single Digit BCD Adder

module bcd_adder(input [3:0]a, [3:0]b, cin, output C, [3:0]D);

    supply0 gnd;
    wire Co;
    wire [3:0]S;
    wire [2:0]orin;

    fourbit_pa PA1(S[0], S[1], S[2], S[3], Co, a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], cin);
    
    and U4(orin[0], S[3], S[2]), U5(orin[1], S[3], S[1]);
    or  U6(orin[2], orin[1], orin[0]), U7(C, orin[2], Co);

    fourbit_pa PA2(D[0], D[1], D[2], D[3], S[0], S[1], S[2], S[3], gnd, C, C, gnd, gnd);

endmodule

//Testbench
module mut_bcd_adder;

    reg [3:0]a;
    reg [3:0]b;
    reg cin;
    wire C;
    wire [3:0]D;

    bcd_adder mut_bcd_adder(.a(tb_a),.b(tb_b),.cin(tb_cin), tb_C, tb_D);
    
    initial begin
        
        $display("                 Time a     b    cin    C D");
        $monitor($time,,"%b %b  %b  %b  %b", tb_a, tb_b, tb_cin, tb_C, tb_D);

        #0 tb_cin = 1'b0; tb_a = 4'b0000; tb_b = 4'b0000;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b0; tb_a = 4'b0011; tb_b = 4'b1001;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b0; tb_a = 4'b1000; tb_b = 4'b0111;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b0; tb_a = 4'b0100; tb_b = 4'b0100;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b0; tb_a = 4'b0111; tb_b = 4'b0010;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b1; tb_a = 4'b1001; tb_b = 4'b0110;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b1; tb_a = 4'b0011; tb_b = 4'b0011;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b1; tb_a = 4'b0111; tb_b = 4'b0111;
        #5 tb_cin = 1'b1; tb_a = 4'b0010; tb_b = 4'b0110;
        #5 $finish;
    
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code on different simulators on EDA Playground, you will get slightly more helpful compile error messages.  Taken together, you get a clearer picture of the problem.  For example, with VCS:

```
Error-[MPC] Mixed port connection is not allowed
testbench.sv, 
  The two types of module port connections, by ordered list and by name, shall
  not be mixed.
  Please refer to Verilog LRM(1364-2001), section 12.3.6.

1 error
```

Change:

```
bcd_adder mut_bcd_adder(.a(tb_a),.b(tb_b),.cin(tb_cin), tb_C, tb_D);
```

to:

```
bcd_adder mut_bcd_adder(.a(tb_a),.b(tb_b),.cin(tb_cin), .C(tb_C), .D(tb_D));
```

The point is that you need to use the same port connection style for all the ports.

---

You have other syntax errors that you need to fix.  You need to declare all the signals in the testbench: `tb_a`, `tb_b`, etc.